# How to remove a jar from Mule ESB Runtime server in Anypoint Studio?

Tags: mule-studio, mule-esb

I have created an ESB application which fails to execute the flow because the library `js-engine-1.1-jdk14.jar`  is present in Mule Runtime server 3.9.0 Community Edition. 
So I want to know how can I remove this jar `js-engine-1.1-jdk14.jar` from the mule runtime server in Anypoint Studio so that my flow can execute properly.

Error is :

> com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "load" is not
>   defined. (#3) in  at line number 3

Answer (score 0):

You should never remove a jar from the runtime, under risk of breaking it. Same with thing with overriding or updating them. Instead, at least for Mule 3.x, you have to adapt your application to the libraries provided.

You didn't mention what was the error or problem why it fails. If the application is using a different and incompatible version than the one provided, then it needs to be modified to use the same one than the runtime.

In the EE you have the alternative method of [fine grained class loading control](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/fine-grain-classloader-control) though it is not useful for every use case.

Comment: I have added the error info in the question. Also, i have removed the jar from the Mule ESB server when i deploy it outside the Anypoint Studio and it works. So I think for me removing the jar from Anypoint Studio should not break anything.

Comment: Is the application packing a Javascript library and which version?

Answer (score 0):

The lib can be found inside plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.9.0_6.4.0.201710051922\mule\lib\opt. We can remove it from there.

Comment: It is not a best practice to change a library from the runtime. It is best to understand the incompatibility and see which alternatives are there.